# rxjava2 - simple example of executing tasks on a thread pool, subscribing on a single thread

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm experimenting with the following task to get my head around RxJava:

- Given a list of URLs
- Do a HTTP request for each URL on a thread pool
- For each result insert some data into an SQLite database (no multithreading here)
- Block the method until it completes

So I tried it out in Kotlin:

```
val ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
Observable.fromIterable((1..100).toList())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(ex))
    .map { Thread.currentThread().name }
    .subscribe { println(it + " " + Thread.currentThread().name }
```

I expected it to print

```
pool-1-thread-1 main
pool-1-thread-2 main
pool-1-thread-3 main
pool-1-thread-4 main
....
```

However it prints:

```
pool-1-thread-1 pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1 pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-1 pool-1-thread-1
```

Can anyone correct my misunderstandings about how this works? Why does it not use all of the threads of the thread pool? How can I get my subscriber to run on the main thread or block until completion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rx is not meant as a parallel execution service, use Java's streams api for that. Rx events are synchronous, and will flow through the stream subsequently. When building the stream, observeOn will request a thread once and process the emissions one by one on that thread.

You also expected `subscribe` to be executed on the main thread. `observeOn` switches the threads and all downstream events happen on that thread. If you want to switch to the main thread, you will have to insert another `observeOn` just before `subscribe`.

Comment: Looks like the only thing @bcoughlan missed was `subscribeOn()`, the answer is not correct at all.

Answer (score 2):

To make code inside your `map` block work in parallel you should wrap it to observable with own scheduler:

```
val ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
    val scheduler = Schedulers.from(ex)
    Observable.fromIterable((1..100).toList())
            .flatMap {
                Observable
                        .fromCallable { Thread.currentThread().name }
                        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            }
            .subscribe { println(it + " " + Thread.currentThread().name) }
```

In this case, you will see the result:

```
pool-1-thread-1 pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2 pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-3 pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-4 pool-1-thread-1
...
```

You can check article [RxJava - Achieving Parallelization](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.sg/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html) that gives explanations of this behavior.

Also, RxJava 2.0.5 introduced [ParallelFlowable API](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Parallel-flows)